# find files using regex with exact digits number

Tags: regex, file, find, digits

I'm trying to find all files on linux that would match files like these:

```
frontend_prod_20100112.log
frontend_prod_20110101.log
frontend_prod_20120101.log
frontend_prod_20121231.log
```

the only variable here is 8 digits inside (exactly 8). I'm trying to run:

```
find . -regex ".*frontend_prod_[0-9]{8}\.log"
```

or

```
find . -regex ".*frontend_prod_(\d){8}\.log"
```

but it doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this is POSIX, you need a slightly different syntax:

```
find . -regex ".*frontend_prod_[0-9]\{8\}\.log"
```